# Python/Pandas -- convert day and hour columns into index of hour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data Frame that looks like this:

```
df
         Date    Hr    CO2_resp
0      5/1/02   600    0.000889
1      5/2/02   600    0.000984
2      5/4/02   900    0.000912
```

How would I go about creating a column `Ind` that represents a number index of hours elapsed since midnight 5/1/02? Such that the column would read

```
df
         Date    Hr   Ind      CO2_resp
0      5/1/02   600     6      0.000889
1      5/2/02   600    30      0.000984
2      5/4/02   800    80      0.000912
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you loading it from a text file? do hours normally have a zero before? `0600`?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes. The hours do not normally have a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html). Then convert `timedelta` to `hours` by `np.timedelta64(1, 'h')` and last if `type` of output is always `int`, cast by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
#convert column Date to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df['Ind'] = ((df.Date 
              - pd.to_datetime('2002-05-01') 
              + pd.to_timedelta(df.Hr / 100, unit='h')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')).astype(int)
print (df)
        Date   Hr  CO2_resp  ind
0 2002-05-01  600  0.000889    6
1 2002-05-02  600  0.000984   30
2 2002-05-04  900  0.000912   81
```

If not dividing by `100` column `Hr`, output is different:

```
df['Ind'] = ((df.Date 
              - pd.to_datetime('2002-05-01') 
              + pd.to_timedelta(df.Hr,unit='h')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')).astype(int)
print (df)
        Date   Hr  CO2_resp  Ind
0 2002-05-01  600  0.000889  600
1 2002-05-02  600  0.000984  624
2 2002-05-04  900  0.000912  972
```

Comment: Hmm, but for me is not clear why is neccessary divide column `Hr` by `100`

Comment: In my case, the column has to be divided by zero, because I need to know hours since the start of experiment on midnight 05/01/12. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `Date` is a string, and `Hr` is an integer, you could apply a function to parse the `Date`, get the hours (days * 24) from the [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) with your reference date, and add the hours.

Something like this -

```
df.apply(lambda x: 
     (datetime.datetime.strptime(x['Date'], '%m/%d/%y')
      - datetime.datetime.strptime('5/1/02', '%m/%d/%y')).days
     * 24 + x['Hr'] / 100,
     axis=1)
```